# AngularJS method of using multiple services for one controller?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I don't know if this is appropriate for question, but here it is:

My app contains a lot of different forms, I want to submit them using angular (and laravel), this is how it looks like:

```
app.controller("uploadController", ['$scope', '$sanitize', '$location', 'UploadService', 
    ($scope, $sanitize, $location, UploadService) -> 
        $scope.upload = ->
            formType = $sanitize($scope.formType)
            ##switch case for `UploadService` to gain data of what form it is
            ##Ex:
            ###
                switch(formType): {
                    case ('uploadFormNews'):
                        UploadService.save
                            data1: $sanitize($scope.data1)
                            data2: $sanitize($scope.data2)
                        , (->
                            $scope.alert = ''
                        ), (response) ->
                            $scope.alert = response.data.alert
                        break;
                    case ('uploadFormMember'):
                        UploadService.save
                            data3: $sanitize($scope.data3)
                            data4: $sanitize($scope.data4)
                        , (->
                            $scope.alert = ''
                        ), (response) ->
                            $scope.alert = response.data.alert
                        break;
                }
            ###
])
```

Now my question is, how to determine different services for different cases like these? I tried this:

```
app.factory("UploadService", ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    $resource "upload/news" //for news form
    $resource "upload/member" //for member form
])
```

Obviously it's not working, something is incomplete (like to know for which `case` will use what `$resource`). Any way around this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i have understood the question correctly. Your factory should return a object, with these resources defined.

```
app.factory("UploadService", ['$resource', function($resource)
{
return  {
    news:$resource("upload/news"), //for news form
    member:$resource("upload/member") //for member form
}
}]);
```

I the controller then you call

> ```
> UploadService.news.save(data); //For saving news
>
> UploadService.member.save(data); //For saving member
> ```

Comment: yes you understand the question correctly, and a very nice solution, thanks (can acc ans in 2 minutes)